# Mysql, specific ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

I have such table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `superTable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lotID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `characterID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `confirmChoice` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmStatus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateCreate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateStart` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateEnd` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

I need such order

1. First entries where confirmChoice is null.
2. Next entries where confirmChoice and dateStart is not null.
3. All next order by dateEnd;

How can i do it in one query?

Comment: Try order by with when case then. Ask if any problem

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM superTable WHERE dateStart IS NOT NULL ORDER BY confirmChoice ASC dateEnd ASC`not do what you need?

Comment: of course not, I need select all entries, and only then do specific order

Comment: and why I've got minus? it's SO easy? hey smart guy (who set minus) show how to do it =\ I really hate stack because of this

Comment: @Jain and how it should look like? 

"case when confirmChoice IS NULL THEN *WHAT?*"

Comment: The minus represents a question that "does not show any research effort". This question has been seen thousands of times. I did not downvote you, but only because you already have -1 and I believe it is enough. You should be happy this question is not already closed.

Comment: @Sebas if "This question has been seen thousands of times." why question was open? where is link... From anyone about this? WHere? Everybody SO smart and say 'it was discussed', you mb discuss, NOT I that's why I ask here, stack really becomes ***y thing

Comment: @Sebas how can I represent any reaseach if I do not know even by what query I should search this thing, everything i found wasn't my solution. I should show ppl half internet (by links) and say 'this is NO what i'm searching for'?

Comment: @user1954544, check this answer it helps to understand u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly , this could be one way of achieving it :

```
SELECT
     *
    ,CASE
        WHEN (`confirmChoice` IS NULL) THEN '1'
        WHEN (`confirmChoice` IS NOT NULL AND `dateStart` IS NOT NULL ) THEN '2'
        ELSE '3'
     END AS sort_order
FROM
    `supertable`
WHERE
    1
ORDER BY
     sort_order
    ,`dateEnd`
```

You probably would need to tweak it to suit your requirement .